# Passing entitymanager from reflection method

Tags: jpa, struts2

We are using struts2, EJB with JPA.

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager; // Here I am getting the entitymanager
```

Reflection

```
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, params); //Here params will accept only Class<?>
```

Now I want to pass the `entitymanager` using reflection. How to pass the `entitymanager` in `getDeclaredMethod`?

Comment: no idea what you're trying to ask. Pass the EntityManager from where to where? why not provide details of these "methods" you talk about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Billy, thanks for your reply.

Now We fixed that issue using TransactionScopedEntityManager.

We am using struts2 + EJB + JPA 1.0 (CMT). We have many action classes and the form values will be persist in DB. Initially we created EJB for every one action. Now we are planing to one ejb for all action classes. For that we go for reflection.

Using getDeclaredMethod, we can pass method name and params. Here params will only accept classes. But we need to pass our form object and entitymanager. We used EntityManager type, now we changed to TransactionScopedEntityManager.

Comment: `Initially we created EJB for every one action` : holy cow ! O_o