# Struts2, JPA, EJB, Reflection

Tags: jpa, reflection, struts2, ejb

I have created a project using struts2 and JPA1.0, EJB. My project flow is Action class -> EJB interface -> Service class.
From action I am calling the EJB local interface, the stateless implementation class.
From implementation class I am calling the service class using reflection. So, I am using only one EJB for calling all service classes from action.
Is this a correct way?

Comment: This is primarily opinion based. BTW don't worry, it's not wrong to have a single EJB used as a facade. The wrong thing is that you're using JPA 1 while you should use JPA 2.

Comment: Hi Andrea, Thanks for your reply. But, I am using JBoss 5, and it is not supporting JPA 2.

Comment: That should be upgraded too :) P.S: now [I remember you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26121270/1654265). Well, your design is much more correct *now*, imho.